# How to pass function search_click() more than two request_url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to set function `search_click()` more than two `request_url`.

I have a `function search_click` as below, and I have three user types with different `request_url`(Please attention: the `user_type` of some users sometimes are both `admin` and `admin_a`, even one user has three user types in the meantime):

```
function search_click() {
  var type = $('#jsSelectOption').attr('data-value'),
    keywords = $('#search_keywords').val(),
    request_url = '';
  if (keywords == "") {
    return
  }
  if (type == "test") {
    request_url = "/admin?keywords=" + keywords
  } else if (type == "user") {
    request_url = "/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords
  }
}
```

I tried to change the code above with the one below, but it doesn't work.

```
function search_click() {
  var type = $('#jsSelectOption').attr('data-value'),
    keywords = $('#search_keywords').val(),
    request_url = '';
  if (keywords == "") {
    return
  }
  if (type == "test") {
    request_url = "/admin?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_a?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_b?keywords=" + keywords
  } else if (type == "user") {
    request_url = "/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_a/user?keywords=" + keywords
    request_url = "/admin_b/user?keywords=" + keywords
  }
}
```

Partial code of base.html is as below,

```
  <div class="searchbox fr">
   <div class="selectContainer fl">
        <span class="selectOption" id="jsSelectOption" data-value="course">
          Type of search
        </span>
        <ul class="selectMenu" id="jsSelectMenu">
          <li data-value="test">test</li>
          <li data-value="test_score">test score</li>
          <li data-value="user">user</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <input id="search_keywords" class="fl" type="text" value="" placeholder="Please input keyword here"/>
    <img class="search_btn fr" id="jsSearchBtn" src="{% static 'img/search_btn.png' %}"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your intentions with the code because I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to achieve. `request_url = "/admin_b?keywords=" + keywords`  just reassigns that variable 3 times. And even then it seems like the code is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue by creating three base.html and three javascript.js for different requested_url with different user types, I know it's not the best and perfect way, it's stupid and complicated, but It's the only way for me so far, after I tried all ways what I knew and searched.

Answer (score 0):

This code just reassigns the variable, which means that you end up with the last value that you have assigned to it, in this case `"/admin_b/user?keywords=" + keywords`.

```
request_url = "/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords
request_url = "/admin_a/user?keywords=" + keywords
request_url = "/admin_b/user?keywords=" + keywords
```

If you want to store all those values in `request_url` variable then you should use object instead of string.

```
// declare request_url like this instead of request_url = '';  
request_url = {
  value1: null,
  value2: null,
  value3: null,
};

if (type == "test") {
  request_url.value1 = "/admin?keywords=" + keywords;
  request_url.value2 = "/admin_a?keywords=" + keywords;
  request_url.value3 = "/admin_b?keywords=" + keywords;
} else if (type == "user") {
  request_url.value1 = "/admin/user?keywords=" + keywords
  request_url.value2 = "/admin_a/user?keywords=" + keywords
  request_url.value3 = "/admin_b/user?keywords=" + keywords
}
```

And then just type `request_url.value1`, `request_url.value2`. `request_url.value3` to access the corresponding values.

Comment: Hi Matus, thank you so much, I've changed code as you pasted,  when I search one item, the url changes to 
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/[object%20Object], and it said, page not found, do I need to change path url in urls.py of django?

Comment: @Begin2Pip I would say no. That `[object%20Object]` indicates to me that you are using that object as a url itself and it is being converted to string. Don't use the object, use the individual values - `request_url.value1` or `request_url.value2` or `request_url.value3`.

Comment: I did not use the object Matus, I userd request_url.value1 or request_url.value2 or request_url.value3, it changed to [object%20Object] by itself.......

Comment: @Begin2Pip What is the value of `keywords` in `"/admin?keywords=" + keywords;`?

Comment: I would like to get the list of users, so value of the keywords is username or department name, oh do I need to change base.html?

Comment: @Begin2Pip If you can, catch the url that is being converted to `[object%20Object]` right before you submit it and copy past that value here.

Comment: Hi I pasted my partial code of base.html, I don't know how to do about what you said......

Comment: @Begin2Pip You must submit that value to the backend somewhere in your code, button click or something like that. Place console.log(url) before it is submitted and you will see that value. My guess is that there is a problem with that value, meaning that it is a compound object that is being converted to string.

Comment: Do you have any complete samples about `request_url.values`? I still don't know how to change..........I am newbie on Javascript......

Comment: @Begin2Pip How can I have them? It is your application and I have absolutely no idea what you are submitting. I can't help you more without seeing values that you are submitting.

Comment: I submitted nothing dear, only search keywords `username`, `department`, my code and values are similar like this link's https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/32753535